# Is there a way to show stepwise how Clojure evaluates a function?

Tags: clojure, applicative

I'm just starting to teach myself Clojure.  As part of supplementing my studies I've watched a few UC Berkley lectures by Brian Harvey on the topic of functional programming.  In his [second lecture on functional programming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFxGVf3KAto), at about minute 34, he uses the **applic** function to show the order of evaluation.  Does Clojure have a feature similar to this?  It sure would be handy to see the order of evaluation as I work to understand the whys and wherefores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do just in REPL (answer by Mike Meyer in Clojure mailing list: [Debugging in Clojure](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/2255043f48332a55))

```
=> (use 'clojure.contrib.trace)
nil
=> (defn foo [coll] (reduce + coll))
#'web-db.core/foo
=> (defn bar [coll] (map inc coll))
#'web-db.core/bar
=> (dotrace [foo bar] (foo (bar [1 1 1])))
TRACE t3868: (bar [1 1 1])
TRACE t3868: => (2 2 2)
TRACE t3869: (foo (2 2 2))
TRACE t3869: => 6
6
```

there are also Clojure Debugging Toolkit
("Ridiculously long instructions on how to use it are here:
http://georgejahad.com/clojure/emacs-cdt.html ")

And some IDE (like Eclipse with Counterclockwise plugin) allow to debug: to set breakpoints, see locals, step in/out, ...

Comment: the problem with trace library is that it doesn't support built-in operators, like `+`... I remember, it was more advanced tracer, but couldn't remember its name